# Get OneToMany 'Child' to return object of 'Parent' if relationship is present

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex, doctrine-query

Using the doctrine docs example below, I would like to be able to return the all features when querying for a product.

So effectively `selecting all products where feature.product_id = product.id`

But would like to do this the doctrine object oriented way if possible. Is there any way in doctrine to match these relationships the opposite way?

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity **/
class Product
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="product")
     **/
    private $features;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->features = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity **/
class Feature
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="features")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $product;
    // ...
}
```

Source: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Thanks,

Comment: Correct me if I wrong but this is roughly what you are thing to do: Retrieve only those products that **have** features assigned, but skip those products which **have no** features. Am I right?

Comment: exactly @JovanPerovic sorry for the delayed response

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a product in this case, where product.id = feature.product_id will only return 1 result, assuming your product table's id is its primary key, auto incremented.  Are you sure you're not trying to return all *features* where feature.product_id == (specific product.id)?

If the latter is the case,

```
$features = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Feature')
    ->findBy(
        array('product_id' => $productId)
    );
```

Where you have the $productId, a unique integer, in hand.

Comment: Hi, no i wanted all features that were linked to a specific product a feature being 'sizes' for example

Comment: The code in my answer should return all features linked to a specific product, where you have the product entity and therefore the product id.  If this is not what you want, you might consider revising your question.

Comment: going off of Jovan's comment, "Retrieve only those products that have features assigned, but skip those products which have no features"